# Layout design / UI Design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, android, applications

I am new to android programming and i want to learn how to design my own app , what do i mean by this is designing the app layout from scratch. I couldn't find any tutorial , all things that i get when i search for this thing are photoshop designers that are making the layout as a single image in adobe photoshop. My question refers to designing an app layout from scratch and implementing it in my application.

Comment: Hi GDaniel, welcome to GDSE. Could you please [edit] your question to explain in a bit more detail what you're having trouble trying to do? Currently I'm struggling to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Done , i hope you'll understand now.

Answer (score 0):

On the Photoshop side the only thing you can do is designing and slicing the final UI into smaller bits.
The implementation of the design is 99% of code work in the android section.
You have to set backgrounds, but the buttons into place and even the smallest spaces are either slices you have to put together again or distances you have to code to set.

Comment: I understand, can you provide me some links about some beginner tutorials for designing an app to android ? Thanks a lot.